# Change color on my Javascript made table with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colors, html-table

I have two input boxes to put in height and width, and a button to make a table with Javascript.
Now I want to make the color in each cell change as I hover over them. Preferably with jQuery.

```
    function createTable(inRows, inCols) {
       var inRows = document.getElementById('height').value;
       var inCols = document.getElementById('length').value;

       var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

           var tbl = document.createElement("table");
           var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

            for (var i = 0; i < inRows; i++) {
                var row = document.createElement("tr");

            for (var j = 0; j < inCols; j++) {
                var cell = document.createElement("td");
                row.appendChild(cell);
            }

            tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }

        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        body.appendChild(tbl);
    }   

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('black');
    });
});
```

In my feeble beginner mind, this looks right. But.. its not.
Am I on the right track. And how do I make it happen?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to why it's not right? What happens? What error message do you get?

Comment: You should not use javascript for this. CSS exists for this kind of things.

Comment: @dfsq - It looks like a javascript/jQuery study exercise, but the point is still valid.

Comment: @OriDrori the question states "Preferably with jQuery"?

Comment: It's a study exercise yes. Tried the CSS way to. Cool.

Comment: @CallanHeard indeed it does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the event handler binding on document ready, but the table is not prepared yet. Just add the handler to the end of the `createTable` function. I've changed the handlers to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so the class will be added and removed when the mouse leave the cell ([fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/2qozbu4x/)).

I've also used .on with event delegation, this means that I only add one (two in this case) event handler to the table, and it will only react to event on the cells. In this way, if you add o remove cells, the event handler will work with them automatically.

```
 function createTable(inRows, inCols) {
       var inRows = document.getElementById('height').value;
       var inCols = document.getElementById('length').value;

       var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

       var tbl = document.createElement("table");
       var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

       for (var i = 0; i < inRows; i++) {
           var row = document.createElement("tr");

           for (var j = 0; j < inCols; j++) {
               var cell = document.createElement("td");
               row.appendChild(cell);
           }

           tblBody.appendChild(row);
       }

       tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
       // appends <table> into <body>
       body.appendChild(tbl);

       $(tbl).on('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
           $(this).addClass('black');
       });

       $(tbl).on('mouseleave', 'td', function () {
           $(this).removeClass('black');
       });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. This was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using CSS to style the table, as you're assigning a class for the hover style you want? If so, you can use pure CSS to achieve this affect:

```
td:hover {background: black;}
```